# Sphinx, snippets and partial word matches

Tags: sphinx, sphinxql

We're using sphinx and snippets to do a basic site search.

```
SELECT id FROM search WHERE MATCH('(@keywords corona)')
```

And we're getting matches on "coronavirus" and "coronary" like we would expect.

But when we later use

```
CALL SNIPPETS(
    'Wuhan Novel Coronavirus - What you need to know',
    'search',
    'corona',
    '<span class="mark">' AS before_match,
    '</span>' AS after_match,
    '…' AS chunk_separator,
    800 AS limit,
    20 AS around,
    0 AS query_mode
)
```

None of these partial matches are being highlighted.

If we search for a full word (replacing "corona" in the `SELECT` and `CALL SNIPPETS` with e.g. "coronavirus") then the full word results are highlighted correctly.

Is there a way we can get `CALL SNIPPETS` to highlight the partial word matches in the first example like it does with the full word results in the second example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just appended "*" to the keyword in `CALL SNIPPETS` like this:

```
    'Wuhan Novel Coronavirus - What you need to know',
    'search',
    '*corona*',
    800 AS limit,
    20 AS around,
    0 AS query_mode
```

But the comment from @barryhunter below makes more sense than my actual solution.

Comment: To 'explain' a bit, you have 0 as query mode, so it NOT using the full index settings in interpreting the 'keywords'. Your 'search' index probably has 'expand_keywords' or even 'enable_star=0' or whatever to enable part word matches. But SNIPPETS call is ignoring all this and accepting plain list of words (it has it own syntex like CALL KEYWORDS, but does support its own basic wildcard). Should be able to use `1 as query_mode`, to make it work as well - ie the $keywords would be interpreted same was as MATCH()